# Syntax error in jquery ajax call

Tags: html, jquery

My **HTML** is like this

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td ><img src="" alt="close" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="addproducts" value="141420">141420</td>
        <td class="prd"><strong><a href=""></a></strong></td>
        <td><a rel="prettyPhoto" href=""><img src="" alt="Product"></a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><img src="" alt="close" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="addproducts" value="1213143">1213143</td>
        <td class="prd"><strong><a href=""></a></strong></td>
        <td><a rel="prettyPhoto" href=""><img src="" alt="Product"></a></td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><img src="" alt="close" /></td>
        <td><input type="hidden" name="addproducts" value="242424">242424</td>
        <td class="prd"><strong><a href=""></a></strong></td>
        <td><a rel="prettyPhoto" href=""><img src="" alt="Product"></a></td> 
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I want select all hidden inputs with name addproducts from this and add to an ajax call.
The problem is that I can't predict how many elements will be there before the code execute.
The **ajax url** i am trying to make will be like this

```
http://mydomain.com?addproducts=141420&q141420=16&addproducts=X945X2MG&qX945X2MG=1&addproducts=8382355&q8382355=10&addproducts=146353&q146353=3
```

my usual code for specific parameters in url will be some thing like this

```
  ajaxManager.add(({
    type: 'GET', url: '/ajaxhandler', data: { addproducts: X945X2MG,qX945X2MG:1}
```

but here i can't use this because of unpredictable parameters.
any way i had made some try which ended up in syntax error.code is this

```
  ajaxManager.add(({
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".antal").find("input:hidden[name='addproducts']").map(function () {
                 return
            type: 'GET', data: {addproducts:this.value,'&q'+$(this).val():$(this).next().val()}
```

EDIT:from Alnitak's post i have tried to edit this .
new code

```
 var data = $(this).parent().parent().find(".antal")
          .find("input:hidden[name='addproducts']").map(function () {
                 return
               { addproducts: this.value}

                data['q' + $(this).val()] = $(this).next().val();
                   }).get().join(',')

  ajaxManager.add(({
            type: 'GET', data: data
```

but unfortunatedly it ended up my ajax call comes like this

```
http://mydomain.com?_=1365768440633
```

I am sure I have made some thing terribly wrong.Cany one help me on this

Comment: Most of the time the Syntax-Error alone tells you, which symbol is wrong at what point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create an object literal with the known keys, and then use `obj[key]` syntax for the variable keys:

```
var data = { 'addproducts[]': [] };

$(this).parent().parent().find(".antal")
       .find("input:hidden[name='addproducts']")
       .each(function () {
            data['addproducts[]'].push(this.value);
            data['q' + this.value] = $(this).next().val();
       });

$.ajax({
    ...,
    data: data
});
```

Note the use of `addproducts[]` to allow encoding of an *array* of values for that particular parameter.  Note that there's not actually a defined standard for passing multiple values with the same key for `x-www-form-urlencoded` data, but this works with PHP.  You should consider changing the way your products are added - perhaps a comma-separated list?

Comment: I have updated my code with the code but failed.updated the question with new details from you please take a look

Comment: @AKS see updated answer - you can't use `.map` on objects, only on arrays.

Comment: ah - `addproducts` still needs fixing, because that can't be supplied more than once normally either.

Comment: this time i got close.just some [] got in to url and at the end of url some unknown value.url:?addproducts[]=141420&addproducts[]=X945X2MG&addproducts[]=8382355&addproducts[]=146353&q141420=16&qX945X2MG=1&q8382355=10&q146353=3&_=1365771385527

Comment: try taking the `[]` out of the code I supplied, but see the caveat in my answer about how there's no standard way to supply multiple values for the same key.  The `_=136...` looks like it got added by jQuery - did you have a `?` in the URL ?

Comment: from my assumption push methode is making problem.If i removed push it adds correctly.but as you may know only one value(first one).New url:?addproducts=146353&q141420=16&qX945X2MG=1&q8382355=10&q146353=3&_=1365773273038